# GWT + MySQL - How create a connection?

Tags: java, mysql, database, gwt

I own a project that I develop using GWT and I'll use MySql like my SGDB. But I've had some troubles to make connection and I yet don't got success. Some erros with "inherits", and I don't know how edit the .xml project for solve this, and develop to get conection and access to DB.

Comment: You'll have to be much more specific about what you're doing and what's wrong, or nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly call MySQL / JDBC / JPA libraries from GWT code;  your GWT code will be translated to Javascript and run in a browser, and you will only have at your disposal what JS in a browser has. You will need to decouple data access and use either RequestFactory, GWT-RPC or some other kind of RPC to connect with your web server, which will perform these operations.

Comment: I follow the same steps like made in greetservice example, but in .xml I had error with inherits, I don't know how configure this .xml. example: error with jdbc Connection, How I configure .xml and I know that in client I'll just call the method defined in others .java, like example in interface. And in web.xml I have to change/configure anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the connection at the server side and create methods so the client can ask for the server the data you want.